# How to calculate the unique number of days between two or more date ranges

Tags: php, laravel

I need to calculate the number of **unique** days in two or more date ranges (start & end dates). The problem comes in when the dates start overlapping (see example below).

### Date range #1 (7 days):

- Start: 2019-06-01
- End: 2019-06-07

### Date range #2 (5 days):

- Start: 2019-06-05
- End: 2019-06-10

### Date range #3 (10 days):

- Start: 2019-06-20
- End: 2019-06-30

Total days: 23 days

Total *unique* days: **20 days**

There is a lot of data to process and dates might span across long periods so I need an effective and speedy way to do the calculation. The project is built in Laravel 5.

Thanks

Comment: Basically you could create new range of dates from the current one. Naive but i guess the most effictive way could be to take the first range and add it into an array. Then the second, check if the begin nor the end is between any range of date in your array, if it is then change the end or the begin of the range in the depending of which one isn't in the range. If it's not then add it to the array and so on for all range of dates. this might create some new overlapping range so do this until all your range does not overlapping anymore and just calculate the diff of all your range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Carbon, you can, for each range, add the all the days between Start and End, and, for each insert, check that the current date is not already in the array.

You will end up with an array of all unique days and you can `count` it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that first example is 6 days difference not 7 days.

> Code

```
<?php

$dateRanges = 
[
    [
        'start' => "2019-06-01",
        'end' => "2019-06-07",
    ],
    [
        'start' => "2019-06-05",
        'end' => "2019-06-10",
    ],
    [
        'start' => "2019-06-20",
        'end' => "2019-06-30",
    ]
];

$uniqueDayDiffCount = 0;
foreach($dateRanges as $dateRange) {
    $start = new DateTime($dateRange['start']);
    $end = new DateTime($dateRange['end']);

    $first = $start;

    /**
     * Check if a new $start date overlaps
     * with the prvious end date ($last) and if so
     * take for calcualtion as start
     * date ($first) the previous
     * end date ($last)
     */
    if (isset($last) && $last > $start) {
        $first = $last;
    }

    $last = $end;

    echo "\n<br>Start: " . $start->format("Y-m-d");
    echo "\n<br>End: " . $end->format("Y-m-d");

    echo "\n<br>Calc for Start: " . $first->format("Y-m-d");
    echo "\n<br>Calc for End: " . $last->format("Y-m-d");

    $diff = $last->diff($first)->format("%a");
    $uniqueDayDiffCount += $diff;

    echo "\n<br>Diff: $diff\n<br>DayCount: $uniqueDayDiffCount";
    echo "\n<br>---------------------\n<br>";

}

echo "\n<br>Total DayCount: $uniqueDayDiffCount";
```

> Result

```
Start: 2019-06-01
End: 2019-06-07
Calc for Start: 2019-06-01
Calc for End: 2019-06-07
Diff: 6
DayCount: 6
---------------------

Start: 2019-06-05
End: 2019-06-10
Calc for Start: 2019-06-07
Calc for End: 2019-06-10
Diff: 3
DayCount: 9
---------------------

Start: 2019-06-20
End: 2019-06-30
Calc for Start: 2019-06-20
Calc for End: 2019-06-30
Diff: 10
DayCount: 19
---------------------

Total DayCount: 19
```